# Would a space station be able to watch a world wide cataclysm and how long would the crew be able to survive for?

Tags: iss, space-station, earth-observation, life-support

I know there is [other](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23510/are-there-any-protocols-the-space-station-follows-if-there-is-an-earth-wide-cata) [questions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4608/how-long-can-a-2-person-crew-survive-on-iss-totally-cut-from-earth) with similar concerns about there being any protocols in pace if the crew of space station were to witness a world wide cataclysm and the survivability of the crew if they were disconnected from the earth. I am wondering if the scenario were to happen, first, would there be events that would affect the ISS?

I am assuming here any world wide cataclysm that doesn't destroy the actual globe would not affect it. I am not sure in the case of an event of something being expelled from the earth (such as the crashing of something on earth such as a massive asteroid that expelled debris) or in cases where the effects can reach the atmosphere at the least (such as fallout from a massive nuclear explosion or something similar)

In addition to wether or not the crew would essentially have front row seats to the apocalypse, what would be extent of time a crew could survive?

Comment: Too broad as written. Depends on the cataclysm.

Comment: It depends on the cataclysm. The ISS could survive a half year long in the lack of resupply. Maybe a year long if the astronauts eat half of their daily ratios. After that, there will be no more food. They can come back with the soyuz any time to nearly any point of the Earth, not only into Kazakhstan. If the Earth becomes a molten lava field, it is not an option and they will all die. If there is only some nuclear war, they might try to target the least problematic regions.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Is there a NRC? (NIST reference cataclysm)

Comment: @uhoh the shuttle flight rules had one for 'an unexpected artificial event' (nuclear detonation) during the countdown....